# Programmatically create fixed width columns in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a table in which each of the columns is as wide as the widest textview.

The first row I'm trying to create will be filled with names.No matter what I try I cannot seem to get all the columns to be the same width. Please note that I do not want to stretch the columns to the width of the screen, if I have to scroll horizontally, that's okay.

So basically if the widest name is 100dp wide, I want every column to be that wide. I figured by setting the weight in my TextViews I would get evenly spaced columns, but that does not seem to be the case.

Here is the code I have so far to create the first row in my table.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detailed_scores);

    game = (Game) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("game");
    TableLayout detailedScoreLayout = findViewById(R.id.detailedScoreLayoutId);

    // First create the row with all the player names.
    detailedScoreLayout.addView(createNameRow());
    }
}
```

```
private TableRow createNameRow() {
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

    for (GamePlayer player: game.getPlayers()) {
        row.addView(createName(player.getName()));
        row.addView(createVerticalDivider());
    }
    return row;
}
```

```
private TextView createName(String name) {
    TextView nameText = new TextView(this);
    nameText.setText(name);
    formatText(nameText, 24);
    return nameText;
}
```

```
private void formatText(TextView text, int textSize) {
    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    int margin = intToDp(12);
    int halfMargin = intToDp(6);
    params.setMargins(margin, halfMargin, margin, halfMargin);
    text.setLayoutParams(params);

    text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textSize);
    text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    text.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
}
```

```
private View createVerticalDivider() {
    View div = new View(this);
    div.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(intToDp(1), TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    div.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    return div;
    }
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: So how are the columns displayed now?

Comment: They are displayed with the width of the text plus the margins I added. Each column is relative to the length of the name inside.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to use a library like
https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView.
it is easy to customize and use.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this. Though I do feel what I want to accomplish should be relatively simple and not require and 3rd party libraries. If this gets the job done then I can live with the extra dependency.